# can negamax be implemented for 4 player chess?(bughouse)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, python-chess

I am seeing that negamax is often used for chess engines.However there is only popular instances of it being used in the conventional game.Is negamax good for the variants of chess like bughouse or is there an alternate algorithm?

Im looking to build a chess variant engine as my project and before i start i want to know the optimised build method.

Comment: Interesting problem... maybe you use four floats to represent the value of each color's position, then negamax minimizes the sum of opponents' values. Have you made any progress or started trying things with this yet?